# Can you declare class name as an attribute of another class in Java?

Tags: java

I have a class called Television and the second class is called Televisionshop and has Television[] television as an array attribute. And also a constructor called Televisionshop(Television [] television). How can I initialize the attribute to this constructor. ?

Comment: Can you show the code that you currently have? It's unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how to assign a field from an argument? `this.television = television`?

Comment: You may want to dig into what Objects are a bit more.  The point of Objects is for you to be able to define objects as real-world concepts and use them as such.  An example would be a car is an object and so you create an INSTANCE of a car.  A car has four tires which have 4 instances of objects.  So the tires are "attributes" of the car.  AND the tires also have attributes and so on.  Tires may have bolts and nuts.  It also might have a rim etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class Television {
    String name;
    
    Television(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}

class TelevisionShop {
    public Television[] televisions;
    
    
    TelevisionShop(Television[] televisions) {
        this.televisions = televisions;
    }
}


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Television t1 = new Television("t1");
        Television t2 = new Television("t2");
        Television[] televisions = {t1,t2};
        TelevisionShop shop = new TelevisionShop(televisions);
        
    }
}
```

I guess this is the most straightforward way.